# Unable to find file in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

The VBE encoder section works (from prior experience but this time around it cannot find the required file. The file is in the `%temp%` folder so there are spaces in the path but I have used the "" as can be seen in the code. The `MsgBox` shows the correct file and I can confirm its existence but the code fails when `fso.GetFile`.

This is part of a larger script that is called with the target file (full path) as the argument. The target file is previously created by the calling script.

Main script (gets called with target file):

```
Set fso      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
textFile     = WScript.Arguments(0)
GetExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(fso.GetFileName(textFile))

If LCase(GetExtension) = "vbs" Then
    Set oFilesToEncode = WScript.Arguments
    Set oEncoder = CreateObject("Scripting.Encoder")
    For i = 0 To oFilesToEncode.Count - 1
        file = """" & Trim(oFilesToEncode(i)) & """"
        MsgBox file

        If fso.FileExists(Left(file, Len(file) - 3) & "vbe") Then fso.DeleteFile(Left(file, Len(file) - 3) & "vbe")

        Set oFile   = fso.GetFile(file)
        Set oStream = oFile.OpenAsTextStream(1)
        sSourceFile = oStream.ReadAll
        oStream.Close

        sDest        = oEncoder.EncodeScriptFile(".vbs", sSourceFile, 0, "")
        sFileOut     = Left(file, Len(file) - 3) & "vbe"
        Set oEncFile = fso.CreateTextFile(sFileOut)
        oEncFile.Write sDest
        oEncFile.Close
    Next
End If

WScript.Quit
```

Section of calling script:

```
Do While fso.FileExists(strTempVBS) = False
Loop

strKey  = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Engineers-Toolbox\Multi-Tool\Installed\Path\"
value    = wshShell.RegRead( strKey )
arg     = " " & strTempVBS
running = "C:\Custom\Multi-Tool\Multi-Tool.exe " & """" & arg & """"
wshShell.Run running, True
```

I have tried using hard coding the path to the exe to get it going, 'value' contains the path to the main script.

Comment: Do you have a error code? Can you give the full file path (include the extension)?

Comment: 'error code 800a0035 File not found' full path is "C:\Users\John Doe\AppData\Local\Multi-Tool\observe.vbs"

Answer (score 2):

Do not prematurely add quotes around paths. I'm always confused why people keep doing this, because it creates more problems than it solves. Add double quotes when they're actually required, but not before.

`FileSystemObject` methods can handle paths with spaces without the additional double quotes. In fact, they will interpret double quotes in a path string as part of the path and throw an error, because they can't find a file with a double quote in its name (which would be [invalid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#naming_conventions) anyway).

Your check for the existence of a file also doesn't work, because you don't account for the quotes you added to the path string:

```
file = """C:\some\folder\file.vbs"""
WScript.Echo file
WScript.Echo Left(file, Len(file) - 3) & "vbe"
```

The output of the above code snippet is

```
"C:\some\folder\file.vbs"
"C:\some\folder\file.vvbe
```

Change this:

```
file = """" & Trim(oFilesToEncode(i)) & """"
```

into this:

```
file = Trim(oFilesToEncode(i))
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Actually I added the double quotes to see if it was a spacing problem, as noted before, this is known good working section *for everything else*. It is a sub part of the script called only when the argument extension is vbs. The changing from vbs to vbe is known good working. So the fault remains as the double quotes were actually only a test.

Comment: @BertB If the quotes are in your actual code it's not possible that this ever worked. If they aren't, why did you put them in your question in the first place? Please update your question with a [mcve], sample input, and the actual complete error message produced by that code and input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution is to (predictably) add the quotes in the calling script, that way the VBS to VBE encoder section can remain standard.

```
strTEMP         = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%UserProfile%" ) & "\AppData\Local\Multi-Tool\"
strTempVBS      = strTEMP & "observe.vbs"
strKey          = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Engineers-Toolbox\Multi-Tool\Installed\Path\"
value           = wshShell.RegRead( strKey ) & " "
running         = value & "" & chr(34) & strTempVBS & chr(34) & ""
wshShell.Run    running ,True
```

Interesting was how the quotes are added. This made the called script find the required file even tho the full path contained spaces.